# Computation of a certain contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I have to do the following integral(using complex analysis):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{nx}}{x^{4}+1} dx $$

So, first I evaluated $x^{4}+1=0 $ and got $x = \pm \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}, \pm \frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}} $

Let, $\Gamma$ be a semicircle(in the upper half-plane) of radius $R$, where $R > 1$  so,

$$ \int_{\Gamma} \frac{\cos{nz}}{z^{4}+1} dz = \int_{\Gamma} \frac{cos(nz)}{(z-z_{1})(z-z_{2})(z-z_{3})(z-z_{4})} dz$$, where $z_{1}, z_{2}, z_{3}, z_{4}$ are the four zeroes of
$ z^{4} +1 = 0$. Then I computed the residues in the following manner:

Res($f$, $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}})$ = $ \lim_{\ z\to\ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{cosnz}{(z+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}})((z-\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}} )(z+\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}})} $

Since, the expression is messy I will call the residue $a$ and doing the same thing to compute the other residue I get $b$.

Then, we notice that on the semicircular arc:

$$ \left|\frac{cos(nz)}{z^{4} +1} \right| \leq \frac{1}{R^{4}+1} $$ and

$$ \left| \int   \frac{cos(nz)}{z^{4} +1}  dz \right|      \leq     \frac{1}{R^{4}+1} .\pi R      $$

So, the integral goes to $0$ as $R \rightarrow \infty$. So, as $R \rightarrow \infty$

$$\int_{\Gamma} f(z) dz  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{nx}}{x^{4}+1} dx = 2\pi i(a+b)$$

So,

$$  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{nx}}{x^{4}+1} dx     = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{nx}}{x^{4}+1} dx = \frac{1}{2}(a+b) \pi i      $$

Is my work correct? If not, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Some things:

- You want to apply Cauchy's integral theorem, so your contour must be closed.  You have a semicircle, but you do not mention the linear segment closing it into the boundary of a half-disk.  You need this segment to be part of your contour, as it is the part that actually is (twice) the integral you want.
- Why do you believe $|\cos(n z)|$ is bounded by $1$ on the semicircular part of $\Gamma$ (as the radius increases)?  $\cos(n z) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} n z} + \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} n z} \right)$, which increases like $\mathrm{e}^{|z|}$ along the positive imaginary axis.  (Sure, the *real* cosine is bounded by $1$, but this is the complex cosine.)
  [image: Mathematica graphics]
  The exponential eventually overpowers any polynomial in the denominator.
  [image: Mathematica graphics]
- Because of the rapid growth away from the real axis, you don't want your contour to go very far from the real axis.  Note that $\cos(x + \mathrm{i} y) = \cos x \cosh y - \mathrm{i} \sin x \sinh y$.  You might have more luck with two parallel rays, one above the pole in the first quadrant, one along the positive x-axis, with a short line segment descending the imaginary axis to join the ends of the rays.  (Just a guess : I haven't checked that this is "easy".)
- Also, you are integrating a real integrand over a real interval.  If you don't get a real result, something has gone terribly wrong.

Comment: The issue of "growing $|\cos nz|$" is solved by using $e^{inz}$ instead.

Comment: @metamorphy : That would work.  Note to the OP: this only makes the *upper* half-plane's contribution small.  If, in a future problem, you are thinking of doing this in the lower half-plane, $|\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} n z}|$ is not small as one heads toward $-\mathrm{i}\infty$.  Maybe $\Re(\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} n z })$ would rescue this idea for that hypothetical future problem.

Comment: @metamorphy Could you clarify what you mean by using $e^{inz} $ here?

Comment: @thecatinfinity : I've already hinted at it.  $\Re(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}nz}) = \mathrm{e}^{-\Im(z)} \cos(\Re(z))$.  Notice you are letting $\Im(z) \rightarrow \infty$.  ($\Re$ and $\Im$ are the real part and imaginary part operations.  This is an application of [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).)

Answer (score 0):

Since the integrand is even, therefore we can transform the integral as

$\displaystyle I=\frac{1}{2} \Re \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}
^{\infty} \frac{e^{nx i}}{x^4+1}d x }_J \tag*{} $

Let’s evaluate $J$ by using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the path

$ \displaystyle \gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where } \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R) \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t} (0<t<\pi) \tag*{} $

Denotes the two simple poles inside $\gamma$ by $z_1=e^{\frac{ \pi}{4}i}$ and $z_2=e^{\frac{3\pi}{4}i}$, then letting $R \rightarrow+\infty$, we have

$\displaystyle J= 
\oint_\gamma \frac{e^{n z i}}{z^4+1} d z
=2 \pi i\left(\frac{e^{nz_1i}}{4 z_1^3}+\frac{e^{nz_2 i}}{4 z_2^3}\right)  =2 \pi i\left(\frac{z_1 e^{nz_1 i}}{4 z_1^4}+\frac{z_2 e^{nz_2 i}}{4 z_2^4}\right)=-\frac{\pi i}{2}\left(z_1 e^{nz_1 i}+z_2 e^{nz_2 i}\right)\tag*{} $

Noting that $z_2=-\bar{z}_1$, we can convert $J$ into

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}J&=-\frac{\pi}{2}\left(z_1 i e^{nz_1 i}+z_2 ie^{-n\overline{z_1} i}\right) \\& =-\frac{\pi}{2n}\left(nz_1 i e^{nz_1 i}+\overline{nz_1 i e^{nz_1 i}}\right) \\& =-\frac\pi{n} \cdot \Re\left(nz_1 i e^{nz_1 i}\right) \\& =-\pi \cdot \Re\left(\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}} e^{\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}n}\right) \\& =-\frac{\pi e^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}}}{\sqrt{2}} \Re\left[(-1+i)\left(\cos \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}+i \sin \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right] \\ & =\frac{\pi e^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}}}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\cos \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}+\sin \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\&\end{aligned}\tag*{} $
Now we can conclude that
$\boxed{\displaystyle I=\frac{\pi e^{-\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2 \sqrt{2}}\left(\cos \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}+\sin \frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\tag*{} $